# Passing DJango template variable as an input parameter

Tags: django, django-templates, forms, http-post

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a template that uses Django's template syntax to generate a list of objects.  I want to create a "form post" on each item to give the option to delete that item from the list.  Pretty simple:

```
MySQL <remove> 
Linux <remove>  
Java   <remove>
Python   <remove>
C++   <remove>
PostgreSQL   <remove>
Django <remove>
```

Where `<remove>` is a "submit".

Here is what the template looks like:

```
{% if not dev.user.is_superuser %}
    {% if dev.user.is_authenticated and dev.user.is_staff %}
       <ul>
       {% for skill in dev.skill_set.all %}
           <form action="/removeSkill/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
           <li>
               {{ skill.skill }}
               <input type="hidden" name="skill" value={{ skill.skill }}>
               <label class="formlabel">&nbsp;</label>
               <input type="submit" value="Remove  &#9658;"></li>
           </form>
       {% endfor %}
       </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

I need to know how to pass the `{{ skill.skill }}` value as the hidden input's `value`.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE 1:

Ok, it looks like what I'm doing in the template is working wonderfully.  I just can't seem to actually delete the entry from the database in the view.

```
def remove_skill(request):
    """
    ..  function:: remove_skill()

        Remove a skill for a developer

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    ## Create a logging object
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logs/')
    filename = '{0}debug.log'.format(path)
    logfile = open(filename, 'w')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    logfile.write('\n --------------------- {0}\n'.format(now))
    if (request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff):
        userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
        devSkills = DevSkills(dev = userProfile, skill = request.POST.get('skill'))
        logfile.write('user =  {0}\n'.format(devSkills.dev_id))
        logfile.write('skill to remove =  {0}\n'.format(devSkills.skill))
        devSkills.delete()
        logfile.close()

    return dev_profile(request)
```

The `debug.log` file shows information for the correct entry, but I continue to get the following error when I try and remove a skill:

```
DevSkills object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was just too early in the morning.

Notice the silly mistake in the view:

```
devSkills = DevSkills(dev = userProfile, skill = request.POST.get('skill')
```

Which, clearly, needed to be:

```
devSkills = DevSkills.objects.get(dev = userProfile, skill = request.POST.get('skill'))
```

I need to get an object to delete - not create one!

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a typo in `devSkills = DevSkills(...)` string. You're actually instantiating new object instead of getting records from the database. You need to use `devSkills = DevSkills.objects.filter(...)` to get the queryset, and then `delete` it.

PS: I would also suggest using [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and Python native [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look into those two tools.  Regarding your solutions - yes, that is exactly what I figured out (and what I posted in my solution :)).

Answer (score 0):

Is the following what you're looking for (parse based on 'name' parameter in view)?

```
   <li> {{ skill.skill }} 
        <input type="hidden" name="skill_{{ skill.pk }}" value={{ skill.skill }}> 
        <label class="formlabel">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Remove  &#9658;"></li>
```

In the `for` loop over `request.POST` you can easily parse using `.split("_")[-1]`.

This is none too elegant. Using `formsets` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) is actually probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I'll try and use `formsets` but that looks like I'll need to do a bit of refactoring to use it properly - it seems overly complicated for such a simple concept.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Will modifying the 'name' parameter work for you in this case? -- actually using `_{{skill.id}}` would probably be better.

Comment: I actually determined that what I am doing is passing the information I want - I just can't seem to delete the entry in the database correctly.  I'll update my question.